# Getting Parent of Parent Using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an disappearing delete animation code and I want to get the entire div "parent_parent" to disappear.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="parent_parent">
    <div class="parent">
        <a href="?delete=1" class="delete_link"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is part of the jquery code that makes the parent_parent div disappear:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.delete_element').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'delete.php',
            data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + parent.parent().attr('id').replace('sort_', ''),
            beforeSend: function() {
                parent.parent().animate({
                    'backgroundColor': '#fff'
                }, 300);
            },
            success: function() {
                parent.parent().slideUp(300,function() {
                parent.parent().remove();
                });
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

But so far no animation happens, but if I just call one parent then the inside div does disappear.  I don't get any error messages either.

Comment: Not sure if its your issue or a miscopy but you are missing a `.` between the last `parent()` and `slideUp`.

Comment: Yes, it was miscopying!  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Also, in your callback function, `parent` isn't defined. You need `$(this)`, and then a reference to what you want.

Comment: @SimpleCoder nice, I bet thats the issue. Should post that as an answer.

Comment: I updated the code...still not getting any results.

Comment: No, `$(this).parent().parent().remove();` should be `$(this).remove()`, just as I had it in my code

Comment: sorry, I had edited this and then I saw your code

Comment: Got it, changed my code to reflect!

Comment: Good. However, I'd suggest that you give each `div` its own ID. That way, you don't need to mess with `parent()` and classes.

Comment: Yes, the divs do have their down IDs.  I'll change the code to reflect that too.  Good suggestion!

Comment: Then you should just select them based on their IDs. Why didn't you post your full code example to begin with? You could have saved yourself a lot of work.

Comment: Trust me, it passed through my mind when I was posting.  I'm sorry.

Comment: Haha it's ok. Once you post the real code I can give you a much better answer.

Comment: Also, do you have more than one of these `delete_link` structures on your page?

Comment: No, just one delete_link structured list on this page.

Comment: Ok. Can you please post the actual code, complete with ids for the divs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is still too complicated for what you are trying to do. This is better:

```
// $(function(){ is shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
    $('a.delete_element').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Don't give thing ambiguous names like 'parent'
        // You should change your class names too.
        var container = $(this).closest(".parent_parent");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'delete.php',
            // You had multiple instances of parent.parent(), but no direct usage of parent alone
            // This is a clue that you can simplify parent.parent() since you are traversing to the same element every time
            data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + container.attr('id').replace('sort_', ''),
            beforeSend: function() {
                containter.animate({
                    'backgroundColor': '#fff'
                }, 300);
            },
            success: function() {
                container.slideUp(300, function() {
                    // Do not repeat the same selector within a callback
                    // That's what `this` is for
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

If you use this code example as it is, it will work.

Comment: I'm not even getting the slide up animation, let alone the remove.  It's saddening.

Comment: I think you need to give us some context here. `success` is probably a callback on an Ajax operation. Please post the code that uses `success`, since that will determine what the first `this` refers to

Comment: Don't know why I missed this when I posted my response, but I like it. Caching the original parent jQuery object will also work, but since the performance would be trivially different I think it would boil down to style preference more than anything!

Comment: Apparently he does cache the parent object in `parent`, though at this point I'm not sure what it refers to.

Comment: Well, that original question has been edited so many times it's hard to tell what was there and what's the result of suggestions by us. ;-) I don't think it was originally there.

Comment: You're right, it wasn't there to begin with. It was just added a few minutes ago.

Comment: @drummer392: I've updated my code. You still haven't posted your real code with the ids.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not preventing the default anchor tag action. You probably also want to cache references that you're going to use multiple times. Here's working code:

```
function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var theParent = $(this).closest(".parent_parent");    
    theParent.slideUp(300, function() {
        theParent.remove();
    });
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VXEUM/

Note also that I'm using `closest()` instead of doubling up on `parent()`. Just a style preference. Plus if your element gets nested more deeply it will still work using `closest()`.

Comment: Updated my response; might still be helpful to you to show caching a jQuery object that is reused. Glad it's working. What was the solution? You can post an answer to your own question and even accept it so that someone stumbling on this question could learn. :-)

Comment: I will, but I don't have 100 rep so I have to wait like 18 hours.